# Как слить значения 2-х массивов по индексам?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть конкретный массив 'data' из 20 строк

```js
var data = [['COMPARABLE'], ['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'],
          ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'], ['Proximite'], ['Auchan Retail Russie'],
          ['Total'],['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'], ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'],
          ['Proximite'], ['Specialise'], ['Ecommerce'], ['Auchan Retail Russie']];
```

И есть массив с данными 'gridData' тоже из 20 строк я его перебираю и добавляю в в массив 'data' Добавляются как еще строки массива.

```js
var data = [['COMPARABLE'], ['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'],
          ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'], ['Proximite'], ['Auchan Retail Russie'],
          ['Total'],['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'], ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'],
          ['Proximite'], ['Specialise'], ['Ecommerce'], ['Auchan Retail Russie']];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.gridData.length; i++) {
          data[i].push(this.gridData[i].data);
        }
```

он добавляется вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А мне необходимо чтобы значения gridData добовлялись в массив data. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать=)

Comment: data[i].push(this.gridData[i].data); замените на data.push(this.gridData[i].data);

Comment: чем текущий вопрос отличается от предыдущего? как это должно быть в итоге?

Comment: @Grundy ты прошлый раз помог стало лучше но если грубо говоря щас массив делается таким data =[comparable [значения gridData'0']], [classique [значения gridData'1']] итд а мне необходимо вот так [comporable, значения gidData'0'], [classicue, значения gridData'1'] итд

Comment: Вот и отредактируй предыдущий вопрос, добавив в него **конкретный** пример данных на входе и на выходе.